# How do I draw a polyline in Leaflet using pixel coordinates?

Tags: leaflet

My map is set up and the markers are in place, and it's working perfectly. I now want to add lines between the markers; so I used the code example from Leaflet and added the coords from a couple markers, but the line isn't showing on the map.

```js
var polylinePoints = [
    [3474, 12427],
    [2298, 11596],
];

var polyline = L.polyline(polylinePoints).addTo(map);
```

Then I tried this...

```js
var pointA = new L.LatLng(3474, 12427);
var pointB = new L.LatLng(2298, 11596);
var pointList = [pointA, pointB];

var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(pointList, {
    color: 'red',
    weight: 3,
    opacity: 0.5,
    smoothFactor: 1
});
firstpolyline.addTo(map);
```

...and the line still isn't showing.

Could the problem be that I'm using pixel coordinates and not actual lat and lng coords? If so, how do I draw lines between markers using pixel coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could the problem be that I'm using pixel coordinates and not actual lat and lng coords? If so, how do I draw lines between markers using pixel coordinates?

Definitely.

Try this:

```
var pointA = map.layerPointToLatLng(L.point(3474, 12427));
var pointB = map.layerPointToLatLng(L.point(2298, 11596));
var pointList = [pointA, pointB];
var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(pointList, {
    color: 'red',
    weight: 3,
    opacity: 0.5,
    smoothFactor: 1
});
firstpolyline.addTo(map);
```

You may run in to problems with origin next, though, see `map.getPixelOrigin()`

Comment: Thanks. This gives me an error `leaflet.js:5 Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, 1154.5312500000002)`, which is pointing to `var pointA = map.layerPointToLatLng(3474, 12427);` And yeah, I tried with `unproject()` on the coords earlier but that didn't work either.

Comment: Ah, make a `L.Point` out of your coords first. Edited.

Comment: That solved the error, but still no line. Tried adding `map.unproject()` to the coords as well, but only got an error. Also replaced `layerPointToLatLng` with `unproject`; no error but no line either. Edit: Never mind, I changed one of the coords to `0,0` and saw a line. Thanks!

Comment: Problem now is that the line doesn't go to the actual coords on the map. Meaning; when I enter two legit coordinates and want to draw the line between them, it doesn't show. But when I put in `0,0` I see the line, so I know it's drawing, it's just off the map? Any thoughts?

Comment: Got it: `var pointA = map.unproject([2099, 11180], map.getMaxZoom());`