# Can I draw with client coordinates in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58839776/how-do-i-draw-a-polyline-in-leaflet-using-pixel-coordinates) question, and the answer works ok for me but I would like the drawn polygons (hexagons) not to move or scale with the map.

Is there a way to do besides overlaying an SVG on top of the map and drawing on it?

Comment: You want to draw hexagons, but those hexagons will not move or scale with the map?  I don't see why you would try to do this within the leaflet library at all, it seems like its an entity completely independent of the map?

Comment: @SethLutske so you'd just put an SVG on top and draw things there, do I get it right?

Comment: @SethLutske - ach! just realized that if I were to draw on top the SVG layer would be on top of the controls (zoomcontrols, for example)

Comment: You may be able to create a custom map pane and create and svg layer there that is essentially not responsive to map motion.  Or you can render your controls in a div completely separate from your map div.  Each one of these probably deserves its own question, though there are already [some discussions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186131/placing-controls-outside-map-container-with-leaflet) on how to put leaflet controls outside the map div.